# How to specify that a generic method returns a non-nullable reference type?

Tags: c#

Consider the code below. As shown in the image, with nullable reference types enabled the inferred type of `foo` is `string?`, even with the constraint `T : notnull`.

Is there some way to modify the method `Bar` and/or the argument passed to `Bar` so that the inferred type of `foo` instead becomes `string`?

I want to be able to use `var foo = Bar(() => "")` and not forced to use `string foo = Bar(() => "")`.

```
private void Foo()
{
    var foo = Bar(() => "");
}

private T Bar<T>(Func<T> bar) where T : notnull
{
    return bar();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335449/how-do-i-specify-any-non-nullable-type-as-a-generic-type-parameter-constraint

Comment: `var` declarations are inferred to be nullable regardless of the nullability of the expression they're assigned from. This is deliberate, and has nothing to do with generics. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62685673/4137916).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you. That question actually answers my question unlike the one it was marked as duplicate of.